# Redux api state not updating in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

I have a vehicle form component that asks for the year, make, and model. After user selects the year I am dispatching a redux action to fetch all makes for that year, and then after selecting a make I am dispatching an action to get all models for that make.

So far when I select the year I can see that the api is called, but the state for make does not update in console.log or on the page. If I select a different year, the api is called again and the list of makes from the first call displays on the page.

I've tried putting mapstatetoprops in the page and passing it as state to the vehicleForm component and also calling mapstatetoprops directly in the vehicle form, but nothing changed.

actions.js

```
export const loadMake = (data) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    //vehicle Loading
    dispatch({type: MAKE_LOADING})

    await axios
        .post(`${keys.redirectDomain}/api/vehicle/getMake`, data)
        .then(res => dispatch({
            type: VEHICLE_MAKE,
            payload: res.data,
        }))
        .catch(err => {
            // dispatch(returnErrors(err.response, err.response))
            dispatch({
                type: VEHICLE_ERROR,
                payload: err.response
            })
        })
}
```

reducers.js

```
const Vehicle = (state = INIT_STATE, action = {}) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case VEHICLE_LOADING:
            return {...state, loading: true};
        case MAKE_LOADING:
            return {...state, makeLoading: true, make: []};
        case MODEL_LOADING:
            return {...state, modelLoading: true, model: []};
        case VEHICLE_MAKE:
            return {...state, loading: false, makeLoading: false, make: action.payload};
        case VEHICLE_MODEL:
            return {...state, loading: false, modelLoading: false, model: action.payload};
        case VEHICLE_ERROR:
            return {...state, loading: false, error: action.payload};
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

functions from vehicleform.js

```
//function called when a new year is selected
    const changeYear = (e) => {
        setYear(e.target.value);
        console.log(year)
        dispatch(loadMake({year: year}));
        setSelMake('Make');
    } 

//part of component where data is displayed
        {modelLoading &&
            <CircularProgress />
        }
        {!modelLoading &&
        <FormControl>
        <Select value={selModel} onChange={changeModel}>
            <MenuItem value={type}>{type}</MenuItem>
            {model.map((item, index) => (
                <MenuItem key={index} value={item}>{item}</MenuItem>
            ))}
        </Select>
        </FormControl>
        }
```

Comment: Figured this out, state/setYear was not updating before dispatching to loadMake. I switched it to dispatch(loadMake({year: e.target.value})

Comment: You may want to add your solution as an answer to your own question to indicate it's already been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of updating state and calling it in the same function, I used e.target.value instead and it solved the issue.

```
//function called when a new year is selected
    const changeYear = (e) => {
        setYear(e.target.value);
        console.log(year)
        dispatch(loadMake({year: e.target.value}));
        setSelMake('Make');
    }
```